# How you can create secondary index when using redisson library

Tags: redis, distributed-caching, redisson

Wanted to know how to create secondary index in Redis when using spring data Redis using redisson Redis library using write through implementation. I am using rmap implementation to store the entity objects.

Tried @indexed annotations in my entity object . It doesn’t seem to create index .

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/dengliming/redis-modules-java? It's an extension of Redisson that let's you utilize RediSearch for secondary index

Answer (score 0):

Live object Service supports secondary indexes

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services/#923-search-by-object-properties